# Passing variable length parameters to a function in python

Tags: python, parameter-passing

This question, though specific in nature, can be abstracted to a general question about Python.

Imagine there is a function that takes in a few parameters. This list of parameters is of variable length; however, the types of the given parameters are not variable. The parameters come in groups of three, and the first and second are lists of floats and the third is a string. Then it repeats. So, in a way, the parameters are **not** of variable length, it's restricted to multiples of 3.

The types can be anything, those are just the ones specific to my problem. I have a matplotlib plot function that looks like this in the docs:

```
a.plot(x1, y1, 'g^', x2, y2, 'g-',...)
```

As you can see, number of groups of three can be however long you want.

I have a list of lists that contains all of my x values (x1, x2, x3, ...) and a list of lists that contain all of my y values (y1, y2, y3,...). Not knowing how long those lists are (they are always equal in length to each other, though), and assuming I can have some dictionary that maps certain indexes to certain strings (for the string parameter), how can I pass indexes from variables length list of lists to this function.

Ideally, I guess it would look something like this is pseudo-code:

```
for element in list_of_lists:
    myFunction(lists_of_lists[element])
```

Except that this code would just execute the `myFunction` for all the elements in the list_of_lists. Instead, I want one long list of parameters and only execute the function once. I also feel like this problem is interested for Python as a whole, not just my specific issue. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think the simplest way to do this would be to use a list of tuples: `[(x1, y1, 'g^'), (x2, y2, 'g-')]`, etc. If the arguments only make sense when all three are provided together, use a data structure that keeps them together. To actually create such tuples from your list of lists, the `zip` builtin is probably the starting point, although your dictionary of string indices will complicate things.

Comment: What I mean is, given the tuples, how do i turn [(x1, y1, 'g^'), (x2, y2, 'g-')] into plot(x1, y1, 'g^',x2, y2, 'g-')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given n lists of equal length (for example):

```
a = [x1, x2, x3]
b = [y1, y2, y3]
c = ['g^', 'g-', 'g+']
```

[zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) will take one element from each list and put them into a tuple in the order they were passed in.

From our example, `zip(a, b, c)` returns:

```
[(x1, y1, 'g^'), (x2, y2, 'g-'), (x3, y3, 'g+')]
```

Now to pass this to plot:

```
list_of_tuples = zip(a, b, c)
denormalized = [x for tup in list_of_tuples for x in tup]
plot(*denormalized)
```

`[x for tup in list_of_tuples for x in tup]` is a list comprehension that will execute `for x in tup` for each `tup` in `list_of_tuples` and append each x in order to the final list.  In other words, it flattens the list of tuples into a list.

In our example, `denormalized` becomes

```
[x1, y2, 'g^', x2, y2, 'g-', x3, y3, 'g+']
```

It is functionally equivalent to:

```
denormalized = []
for tup in list_of_tuples:
    for x in tup:
        denormalized.append(x)
```

The unpack operator (*) when applied to a list tells python to call that function with each element in the list acting as if it were passed in as a positional argument.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for deciphering my poorly worded question and coming up with awesome code